# Centering text in a div

Tags: html, css

How do I center the plus sign + in the div. It still seems that its 8 pixels from and 5 from the bottom. I can't figure out as to what I am doing wrong:

```
        <div style="background: #ffffff; width: 180px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid #808080;">

            <div style="float: left;"><input style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 3px; height: 15px; width: 160px; border: none;" type="text"></div>

            <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;font-size: 11pt; color: #779297;">+</div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `line-height: (value)px` on the + div, to solve the top/bottom align, and `text-align: center;` to solve the right/left position.