# Position span text in the middle (vertically and horizontally) of a li element

Tags: html, css

How can I position span text so that it is positioned in the middle (vertically and horizontally). I have made a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/r4Dr9/) and this is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="one"><span>One</span></li>
    <li class="two"><span>Two</span></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

li {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
}

.one {
    top: 30px;
    height: 50px;
}

.two {
    top: 150px;
}

li span {
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

The height of the li's can vary. The above is just a reference using fixed heights.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758967/centering-text-in-a-div/14759162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `text-align: center;` on the `li span`, and you'll have to set the top margin accordingly for each to get it down from the top.

Comment: Adding `text-align: center;`, along with a `line-height`, did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `line-height` at the same height as your `li`:

```
li span {
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    line-height:30px;
}
li.one span{
    line-height:50px;
}
```

Here's your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4Dr9/2/

Comment: This is a solution. But not a very good one, if you ask me. What if the li´s height is dynamic?

Comment: If the height is dynamic you should have a different approach. You need to set the `li` as `display:table` and the `span` as `display:table-cell`. The `vertical-align:middle` should work then. Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4Dr9/5/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do tricks with margin or padding.

Give the `<li>` a `display:table;`, and the `<span>` a `display:table-cell;`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xrg4m/)

**CSS to add**

```
li {
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
}

li span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things. First, `height:100%;`, `vertical-align:middle;` does nothing. Also, with `width:100%;` and not specifying text-align, it'll always default to left. I'd personally use padding:

```
li span {
    display:inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100%;
}

.one span {
    padding-top:10px;
}

.two span {
    padding-top:3px;
}
```

I updated your jsFiddle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Added style - 'text-align: center' on li element and it worked for me